# interpretation of cox HR under non-proportional hazard

Tags: cox-model, hazard, proportional-hazards

When the true hazard ratio $\lambda(t)$ is time varying as shown below, I used a standard cox regression to get a hazard ratio. If the hazard ratio of $\lambda=0.78$, how can this value be interpreted? Is it an weighted average of $\lambda(t)$? If so, what would the weight be? Is there a way to formulate the relationship between $\lambda(t)$ and $\lambda$? Thanks in advance.

[image]